# "command" modelName magic value in spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to remove some of the "magic value" impression of `"command"` modelName parameter to create a ModelAndView ?

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = GET)
public ModelAndView render() {
    return new ModelAndView("page", "command", new MyObject());
}
```

One hope was to use a spring constant such as

```
new ModelAndView("page", DEFAULT_COMMAND_NAME, new MyObject());
```

I found `"command"` in the 3 following classes of the spring-webmvc-3.0.5 sources jar:

```
$ ack-grep 'public.*"command"'
org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.java
140:    public static final String DEFAULT_COMMAND_NAME = "command";

org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.java
137:    public static final String DEFAULT_COMMAND_NAME = "command";

org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.java
56: public static final String DEFAULT_COMMAND_NAME = "command";
```

The problem is :

- `BaseCommandController` is deprecated
- We don't use `MultiActionController` and `FormTag`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use on your jsp spring tag `<form:form>`

```
<form:form method="POST" action="../App/addCar">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="brand">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="brand" /></td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="year">Age</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="year" /></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />            
    </td>
</tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

you must write:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/car", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView car() {
return new ModelAndView("car", "command", new Car());
}
```

Because the spring framework expects an object with name "command".
Default command name used for binding command objects: "command".
This name to use when binding the instantiated command class to the request.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html

But when you use html form `<form>` you can write:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/car", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView car() {
return new ModelAndView("car", "YOUR_MODEL_NAME", new Car());
}
```

But on your page

```
<form method="POST" action="../App/addCar">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="YOUR_MODEL_NAME.brand">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="YOUR_MODEL_NAME.brand" /></td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="YOUR_MODEL_NAME.year">Age</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="YOUR_MODEL_NAME.year" /></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />            
    </td>
</tr>
</table>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the default name. If the object is a `User` call it `user`, if it's `Item` call it `item`. If you need a default (for example - for a generic framework), define your own constant.